# Chrome Extension - Element added to gmail compose page not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a chrome extension and I want to add a content to the div element in the compose window of Gmail web page. 
By using the inspect tool in chrome, I got the class of the div, prepend the content but it is not showing.

Manifest.json

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "Gmail Extension",
"description": "Personalised extension for gmail",
"version": "1.0",
"icons": {
  "128": "icon128.png",
  "48": "icon48.png",
  "16": "icon16.png"
},

"content_scripts":[
    {
      "matches": ["https://mail.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["content.js", "jquery-3.3.1.min.js"]
    }
],

"permissions": [  
        "tabs",
        "https://mail.google.com/*"      
      ]
}
```

Content.js

```
$('div#:ug.J-J5-Ji btx').prepend('<p>Test added</p>');
```

Image of the compose window, the div highlighted

[image]

The text element isn't showing
Thanks

Comment: The gmail page builds itself dynamically long after your content script has run. You need to detect the moment the compose elements are added into the page, see [Is there a JavaScript/jQuery DOM change listener?](//stackoverflow.com/a/39508954) - the part about extensions seems helpful in your case since gmail modifies the URL when the compose UI is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to add a checkbox to the Compose window:

```
// listen for the event that is fired when the document has finished loading
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', addUpdateButton, true);
addUpdateButton();

function addUpdateButton() {
    var optionsArea = document.getElementsByClassName("aoD az6");
    if (optionsArea && optionsArea.length > 0) {
        var ecsLabel = document.createElement('label');
        ecsLabel.setAttribute('name','ecsslabel');
        ecsLabel.innerHTML = "Send as ECS: ";
        ecsLabel.setAttribute('id','ecsLabel');
        optionsArea[0].appendChild(ecsLabel);

        var ecs = document.createElement('input');
        ecs.setAttribute('type','checkbox');
        ecs.setAttribute('name','ecsbox');
        chrome.storage.sync.get("ecs_mode", 
            function(val) {
            ecs.checked = val["ecs_mode"];
        });
        ecs.setAttribute('id','ecsOption');
        optionsArea[0].appendChild(ecs);
    }
}
```

and here's the result (actually, I added several checkboxes, but omitted the code for clarity):

[image]